# fseeko, fseeko64; ftello, ftello64 Visual C equivalents

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, unix

Could someone help me by telling what is the Visual C equivalent of fseeko, fseeko64; ftello, ftello64?

Thanks :)

Comment: See e.g. [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx).

Comment: I checked this page already. But there were still differences between fseeko and _fseeki..So I wanted to reconfirm! Thanks for the comment Pileborg :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no functions that returns/use off_t, if you need a 64bit position you can use:
_fseeki64
_ftelli64

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to confirm if _fseeki64 and _ftelli64 were the only options! Thanks mauropellizzer :)

Answer (score 2):

Look here [fseek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [_fseeki64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx), [ftell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), and [_ftelli64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to confirm if _fseeki64 and _ftelli64 were the only options! Thanks spyke :)