# value of offset bigger than long int in fseek

Tags: c, system

we know that the parameters of fseek are :

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)
```

i want to use it with an offset value bigger than long int what is the solution and is there any other functions to replace fseek ? 
The value is (512 * 29358080)

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Related: [fseeko, fseeko64; ftello, ftello64 Visual C equivalents](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11737661/335858).

Comment: also related: [fseek to a 32-bit unsigned offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47739641/427158)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a newer API for huge offsets, `int fsetpos(FILE *stream, const fpos_t *pos);` and `int fgetpos(FILE * restrict stream, fpos_t * restrict pos);` but you cannot use it to specify an *actual* offset.  Too bad the Standard committee overlooked this one.

Some systems have an alternate set of FILE positioning functions with larger offsets:

```
int   fseeko(FILE *stream, off_t offset, int whence);
off_t ftello(FILE *stream);
```

If your system has these and `off_t` is 64 bits, this is your best bet.

Another solution is to use move the file pointer multiple times with `fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_CUR);` until you reach the desired position.  There is no guarantee it will work, but you can try and verify if your system's C library supports 64 offsets for standard streams.