# fseek to a 32-bit unsigned offset

Tags: c, file, types, io, tiff

I am reading a file format (TIFF) that has 32-bit unsigned offsets from the beginning of the file.

Unfortunately the prototype for fseek, the usual way I would go to particular file offset, is:

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

so the offset is signed. How should I handle this situation? Should I be using a different function for seeking?

Comment: What OS are you on? Are you using a 32-bit architecture?

Comment: @melpomene The code needs to work on both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures and can run on different machines and operating systems.

Comment: A TIFF file larger than 2 or 4 jiggabytes is not unusual. Your CRT has an alternative that takes a long long argument, you'll have to look at its docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying this question more deeply and considering the other comments and answers (thank you), I think the simplest approach is to do two seeks if the offset is greater than 2147483647 bytes. This allows me to keep the offsets as `uint32_t` and continue using `fseek`. The positioning code is therefore like this:

```
// note: error handling code omitted
uint32_t offset = ... (whatever it is)
if( offset > 2147483647 ){
   fseek( file, 2147483647, SEEK_SET );
   fseek( file, (long int)( offset - 2147483647 ), SEEK_CUR );
} else {
   fseek( file, (long int) offset, SEEK_SET );
}
```

The problem with using 64-bit types is that the code might be running on a 32-bit architecture (among other things). There is a function `fsetpos` which uses a structure `fpos_t` to manage arbitrarily large offsets, but that brings with it a range of complexities. Although `fsetpos` might make sense if I was truly using offsets of arbitrarily large size, since I know the largest possible offset is uint32_t, then the double seek meets that need.

Note that this solution allows all TIFF files to be handled on a 32-bit system. The advantage of this is obvious if you consider commercial programs like PixInsight. PixInsight can only handle TIFF files smaller than 2147483648 bytes when running on 32-bit systems. To handle full sized TIFF files, a user has to use the 64-bit version of PixInsight on a 64-bit computer. This is probably because the PixInsight programmers used a 64-bit type to handle the offsets internally. Since my solution only uses 32-bit types, I can handle full-sized TIFF files on a 32-bit system (as long as the underlying operating system can handle files that large).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `lseek64()` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lseek64))

```
  #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE     /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>

  off64_t lseek64(int fd, off64_t offset, int whence);
```

With

```
  int fd = fileno (stream);
```

Notes from [The GNU C lib - Setting the File Position of a Descriptor](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Position-Primitive.html)

> This function is similar to the lseek function. The difference is that the offset parameter is of type off64_t instead of off_t which makes it possible on 32 bit machines to address files larger than 2^31 bytes and up to 2^63 bytes. The file descriptor filedes must be opened using open64 since otherwise the large offsets possible with off64_t will lead to errors with a descriptor in small file mode.
>
> When the source file is compiled with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64 on a 32 bits machine this function is actually available under the name lseek and so transparently replaces the 32 bit interface.

About `fd` and `stream`, from [Streams and File Descriptors](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-File-Descriptors.html)

> Since streams are implemented in terms of file descriptors, you can extract the file descriptor from a stream and perform low-level operations directly on the file descriptor. You can also initially open a connection as a file descriptor and then make a stream associated with that file descriptor.

Comment: Wouldn't `fseeko` be more appropriate as a replacement for `fseek`? `lseek64` doesn't work on `FILE *`.

Comment: `lseek64` use a `fd`, but near the top of the answer, there is a way to retrieve the `fd` from a `FILE *`, `int fd = fileno(stream);` ([fileno](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fileno))

Comment: Messing with the underlying file descriptor of a `FILE` sounds like a good way to confuse stdio and corrupt your data.

Comment: I don't need to address files larger than 2^31 bytes. It can 32-bits, it just has to be UNSIGNED 32 bits.

Comment: @TylerDurden Then I don't understand the problem. What's wrong with `fseek`?

Comment: @TylerDurden Edited the answer re. "fileno" (and never had a problem using the `fd` from a stream). Using 64 bits, if you can, removes the current signed integer issue.